# Exercise 19 of The Pragmatic Programmer

Tags: java, language-agnostic

This is taken from Exercise 19 of The Pragmatic Programmer.

A quick reality check. Which of these "impossible" things can happen?:

1. A month with fewer than 28 days
2. stat("." ,&sb) == -1 (that is, can't access the current directory)
3. In C++:  `a = 2; b = 3; if (a + b != 5) exit(1);`
4. A triangle with an interior angle sum ≠ 180 °
5. A minute that doesn't have 60 seconds
6. In Java:  `(a + 1) <= a`

I have some answers but I don't think my answers are "right" (in the sense that it is the answer that the writers were thinking about when they wrote the question).

This is my attempt:

> 1) [September 1752](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071112042136AA82QMh)
>
> 2) *--I think we can skip this, not understanding the question--*
>
> 3) I don't know C++, but is it something to do with threading and volatile variables (like Java) ?
>
> 4) impossible..
>
> 5) [Due to occurence of leap Seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)
>
> 6) `double a = 100000000000000001d;`

I was wondering does anyone know the *correct* answer to these questions?

Comment: Don't they offer answers at the end of the chapter/book? Seems a bit cruel to leave you guessing...

Comment: 4 isn't impossible - see spherical geometry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_geometry

Comment: Off-topic, but 4 is not impossible: in fact no triangle in our reality has 180º due to the fact that space is curved.

Comment: 2 can happen if the permissions were changed on the program's current directory (or it was deleted altogether). 3. can exit with operator overloading

Comment: Also, due to overflow, if `int a` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE` then `(a+1) < a` evaluates to `true`. EDIT: ah wait, MadKeithV already mentioned that...

Comment: What is 10000000000000001d? d what is it mean?

Comment: In 3) a and b could be floats/doubles so the sum of it is a float/double which is then compared with 5.0 (instead of 5). Operator overloading is not really an issue as you can not redefine build in operators for build in types. However the answer below from MadKeithV is more precise (and correct).

Comment: I'm wondering if this wouldn't be better at Programmers.

Comment: 5 can happen with NTP adjustments.

Comment: I can't believe nobody has noticed this : #6 -> true for any negative a.

Comment: @halluc1nati0n what do you mean? `-1` + 1 = 0. which is not <= `-1`

Comment: @Pacerier : My bad - I read it wrong.

Comment: (4) to me also suggests rounding errors in floating-point arithmetic: even if you assume a Euclidean geometry, if you calculate the angles in code, you cannot say "==180.0" in floating point arithmetic, because you will almost always be 0.000001 or something off. In Euclidean geometry, if you calculate angles with infinite precision, you will get 180, although you may have to special case triangles where (say) all the angles are at the same point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

3: If a and b are of class type then the overloaded operator+ could do *anything* (or an overloaded assignment operator, or operator !=, or even an implicit conversion operator for that matter).

4: A triangle on a curved surface does not have an interior angle sum of 180.

6: Overflow in a.

The point of the questions is IMHO  to demonstrate that a lot of "impossible" things do actually happen, and that you might not just be being paranoid when you are programming very defensively.

Comment: what about the assignment operator and implicit conversion constructor?

Comment: @tokage - correct, I added them to my answer.  I'm just glad there weren't any commas in the originally posed question :)

Comment: 3 even simpler int a; int& b = a;

Comment: Regarding the point, while this is a good and useful point to make, I feel the counterpoint is equally important. Nothing is more frustrating than wading through code that's polluted with complexity for handling "impossible" things that are *actually impossible*, per the language specifications, etc.,

Answer (score 7):

`2` can happen quite easily. e.g. If you delete your directory while you're in in it and then execute something. Many programs actually handle this.

```
noufal@sanitarium% ls
noufal@sanitarium% cd
noufal@sanitarium% mkdir /tmp/foo
noufal@sanitarium% cd /tmp/foo
noufal@sanitarium% touch x
noufal@sanitarium% ls
x
noufal@sanitarium% rm -Rf /tmp/foo
noufal@sanitarium% ls
noufal@sanitarium% touch x
touch: cannot touch `x': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

nr 5 happens in the case of [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)